# def handle_voice(message):

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет, только начинаю писать бота в телеграм на питоне, и возник вопрос

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def handle_sticker(message):
    print("пришел стикер")
```

Какую команду нужно указывать, чтобы выражение снизу работало

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
    def handle_voice(message):
        print("Пришло Аудиосообщение")
```

Я хочу выводить информацию о том, что человек записал и отпрвил Аудио-сообщение

Answer (score 1):

```
# отправка, например, .mp3    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['audio'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'вы прислали мне аудио')

# отправка голосового сообщения напрямую боту
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'вы прислали мне голос')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]